# Can you turn off Office Online Server "preview" on some Web Applications?

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-online-server, preview

I have Office Online Server connected to a SharePoint 2016 farm with multiple web applications.  Is it possible to turn off/disable "preview" on some of the web applications or site collections?  Or is this all or nothing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is farm-wide, unfortunately. This is accomplished via a WOPI suppression via [New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spwopisuppressionsetting?view=sharepoint-ps).

Answer (score 1):

You can only turn off/disable "preview" on all web applications, the powershell command should be:

```
remove-SPWOPIBinding -action interactivepreview
```